# send live console data back from server to client using django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a django application running at the server where I am running an executable through python. 
I want to  send the output of that executable live as in I do not want the executable to finish first and send the entire data in one http response, rather I want to send the output in multiple pieces so that the client knows what is happening at the server end.

I dont know where to start, and how to proceed to get this done. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Right now I am doing something very simple like this:

```
popen=subprocess.Popen(list,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,errdata=popen.communicate() #this waits for the executable to finish
return output,errdata
```

EDIT 1:
Right now I have created a website where users can select multiple images, and then I send this as XML HTTP Post request. The executable uses those images to do some stuff, and then returns a response. The server is an Apache server running Django with mod_wsgi.

In one of the comments made by aychedee in his own answer, he suggested emulating websockets by using SockJS or SocketIO with Django.

I am not sure, how that works. Will I be able to upload images through HTTP Post requests, and then communicate using SockJS with Django afterwards.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "executable" a python script?

Comment: No, its not a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a low traffic site with sufficient worker processes then you could use the [StreamingHttpResponse provided in Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse).

You would have to provide it with a generator.

```
import os
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE

def content_generator(command):
    subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    content = None
    while content != '':
        content = os.read(process.stdout.fileno(), 1024)
        yield content
```

In the view you would do something like:

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def my_streaming_view(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(
         content_generator(['cat', '/tmp/some_large_file.txt'])
    )
```

Of course this might still be buffered in other places, at the network or browser level. So when experimenting with it make sure you are sending large amounts of data. At least a megabyte of text. For this reason you might have to look into using a protocol like WebSockets where the data will be received immediately.

Comment: I haven't finished yet :-) got some more code to add, turning a subprocess call into a generator is slightly tricky...

Comment: I dont have a large amount of text. The purpose is to provide 'a remote shell' kind of stuff so that users are not waiting to see the entire output. I will work on this a bit and get back once I make some progress.

Comment: For http://www.RogueShell.com I use websockets via tornado on the server. But it is possible you could emulate websockets without providing websockets on the server... look into SockJS or SocketIO. You might be able to hook either of those up to a Django view.